# Вывод платы Iskra Js из вечного цикла

Tags: javascript

Неделю назад купил набор набор "Йодо" от компании Амперки с управляющей платой Iskra JS. Сначала Iskra JS работала отлично, но после того, как я загрузил код с вечным циклом, внезапно перестала отзываться после попытки подключения. Пробовал возвратить к жизни с помощью BTN1 + Reset и просто Reset, но не получается. Сообщение, выводящееся терминалом - Execution Inter Unable to retrieve board information. Connection Error? Connected to /dev/ttyACM0 (No response from board) Prompt not detected - upload failed. Trying to recover... А когда я пробовал вместо загрузки кода в RAM поставить загрузку кода в Flash - выводит You have pre-1v96 firmware. Upload size is limited by available RAM. Пытался прошивать, но в гайдах писали только про случаи для Windows и MacOs, а у меня Линукс. Что можно сделать? Помогите пожалуйста! Прилагаю скрин.[image: r]

Answer (score 0):

Если актуально - попробуйте, через DFU режим. Последние IskraJS, перешиваются как флешки, вернее не последнии а все, режим стал таким. Но сначала нужно перепрошить через DFU режим. В этом режиме прошивал и в Win  и в Linux, правда детали уже не помню